# Set up a shared memory region between userspace and the kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, shared-memory, kernel-module

I would like to create a shared memory mechanism between the kernel and 1 specific process in userspace. This process will spawn threads that will access this shared memory region.

Setting up the region between the userspace and the kernel does not have to be fast, but once it is done, no syscall should be made by the userspace process in order to write/read from the region and the region should be accessible by any kernel thread (not only the kernel part of the userspace process)

Ideally I would like to come up with something like:

- Userspace allocates *k* bytes in its own address space using mmap() or posix_memalign(), where *k* is typically larger than a page.
- Userspace sends the address returned by mmap() to the kernel using a kernel module or a syscall.
- Kernel uses this address to map this region to its own address space so that it can see everything that gets written in this region also after the process exits the call. This means that the mapping needs to be done elsewhere in the kernel virtual address space

I have managed to come up with an example with a single page, with a kernel module doing something like:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/sched/signal.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>

#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/errno.h>

#include <linux/pagemap.h>


/*
 * Prototypes
 */
static int device_open(struct inode *, struct file *);
static int device_release(struct inode *, struct file *);
static ssize_t device_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t * ppos);

static struct file_operations led_ops = {
    .owner    = THIS_MODULE,
    .open     = device_open,
    .release  = device_release,
    .write =    device_write
};



static char *my_page_address;
static struct page *kernel_page;


static ssize_t device_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf,   s  ize_t count, loff_t * ppos)
{
    int res;
    unsigned long uaddr;
    char addrstr[80];

    unsigned long copied = copy_from_user(addrstr, buf, count);

    struct task_struct *task = current; // getting global current pointer       

    if (copied != 0)
    {
        pr_err("Error);
    }

    //Convert adress to long
    uaddr = simple_strtoul(addrstr, NULL, 0);
    uint64_t new_addr = uaddr;
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "Module received the user adddress %p", uaddr);

    //Locks the current process memory map
    down_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);

    res = get_user_pages(
                 uaddr,
                 1, //resquest 1 page 
                 1, //write enable                  
                 &kernel_page,
                 NULL);
    if (res == 1) {

        pr_err("Storing shared page");
        my_page_address = kmap(kernel_page);            
    }

    //Release the lock 
    up_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);


    return count;
}
```

Now, this seems to work for a single page. But several questions come to mind:

1. Can I extend this mechanism to a larger area than a page? Ideally I would like the kernel to access the memory region the same way the userspace process would do (just by having its own pointer in its own address space)
2. `get_user_pages` can take an array of pointers to vmas corresponding to each page as the last argument. If the userspace allocates a large contiguous buffer in its address space, can I use this vma to remap the same contiguous region in kernel space?
3. From what I have seen from other answers, some people recommend to allocate memory from within the kernel and allow users to mmap to it (For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911425/shared-memory-between-user-space-and-kernel-threads)). But since the address space of the process is visible in the kernel space while the process is making the call, it should be possible to simply remap the part of the user address space to the kernel address space, right?

EDIT: Not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911425/shared-memory-between-user-space-and-kernel-threads). I want to know about a good way of mapping a userspace region to the kernel address space. Not accessing it via `copy_from_user()`

Comment: Can't the kernel access regular shared memory?  So simply creating the shared memory segment let's the kernel access the data.  Presumably, you have some way of telling the kernel where the shared memory is.

Comment: As far as I understood, the kernel will be able to access the userspace memory as long as the process virtual address space is installed. I have a way to tell where a page is, but not a whole memory region. My question is more about how to construct a mapping in kernel address space of a userspace memory region.

Comment: OK; you’re out of my depth, then. I’ve not done enough work that deep in the bowels to have useful information to offer.  Sorry.

Comment: The user address space is visible, but it might be swapped out etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shared Memory between User Space and Kernel Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911425/shared-memory-between-user-space-and-kernel-threads)

Comment: Have you actually read the question? I don't see why this is a duplicate of [Shared Memory between User Space and Kernel Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911425/shared-memory-between-user-space-and-kernel-threads). He asks if it's OK to use `copy_from_user()` which it's not, obviously...